# javascript array sum min max added

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have been struggling with something that is bugging me in Javascript. I'm using .split() to get the value off an input field which has numbers separated by commas, then I use split() to create a new variable with this values as an array, all well there. I have been using console to output the value of the array and I've tried it in two different scenarios and these are the outputs:

1) In an "isolated" website: ["46", "43", "44", "41", "47", "42", "45"]

2) In the production website: ["46", "43", "44", "41", "47", "42", "45", sum: function, max: function, min: function]

What could be changing the array to this? I'm suspecting that underscore.js is the culprit, as it is loaded in web #2 and not in #1.

I only ask because I don't know what else to look for!

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** You can try it here and open console: http://www.cdc-bike.com/tienda | this is the other website: http://www.cdc-bike.com/stage/wordpress/?page_id=732

Some of the code used:

Field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected-brands" id="selected-brands" value="47,42">
```

Selecting values:

```
var selected_brands = $('input#selected-brands').val();
```

Split values:

```
var splitted_brands = brands.split(',');
```

That's all.

Comment: Post actual code please

Comment: @JeffShaver Added sample code and URL.

Comment: I opened the console and got only numbers.

Comment: The output I'm getting is: 

["46", "43", "44", "41", "47", "42", "45", sum: function, max: function, min: function]  cdc-stores.js:61

WEB2: 

["8", "4", "5", "2", "9", "3", "7", "6"] cdc-stores.js:82

Comment: @JeffShaver Really? Now I'm more confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those prototypes are declared in `all.js`, if your problem is looping trough the array use

`for(var i = 0; i < array.length...`

instead of

`for(var i in array) { ....`